# Смена информации

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, ребята. Как сделать:
1) Стоит ссылка Выбор города: Москва
а внизу выводится номер телефона текстом.

При нажатии на Москва выбрать Питер и что бы текст телефона поменялся на новый и обратно.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id='info'>Москва, 654321</div>

$('#info').toggle(function() {
   $(this).html('Питер, 123456');
}, function() {
   $(this).html('Москва, 654321');
});
```

Comment: а если выбор города и телефон в разных частях сайта находится

Answer (score 1):

А если так:

```
$('#info').toggle(function() {
   $(this).html('Питер');
   $ ('name_layer').html('123456');
}, function() {
   $(this).html('Москва');
   $ ('name_layer').html('654321');
});
```